# Not able create a mysql table in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, create-table

CREATE TABLE projec (id TEXT(20),
name INT(50),
location TEXT(20),
locality TEXT(20),
type TEXT(20),
condition VARCHAR(20));

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition VAR
CHAR(20))' at line 6

Comment: I just tried replacing condition column by condtn, It got created. Why am I not able to use condition fully.

Answer (score 3):

Condition is a reserved word and can't be used for things like column names unless it is quoted first.